# using try except to validate

Tags: python, validation, try-except

This is my code for my attempt to validate 4 input codes

```
while True:
            try:
                customer_name = input("Enter updated customer name: ")
                if not customer_name.isalpha():
                    print("Customer names should not contain numbers!")
                    continue
                package_name = str(input("Enter updated package name: "))
                if not package_name.isalpha():
                    print("Package names should not contain numbers!")
                    continue
                number_pax = int(input("Enter updated pax: "))
                pax_cost = int(input("Enter updated cost per pax: $"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input, only numbers allowed!")
                continue
```

What I would like to do is for example, when a user enters a str for `number_pax` it will show an error message but lets users to try again for that specific input. However, my codes brings the user back to the first input code which is `customer_name` How may I do so to let the user continue from the input code they were at and not start from the first one(customer_name) again.

I hope I have worded it properly enough, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way is to split the validation routines into separate functions, and track (via a list, tuple or dict) the progress and revisit (re-call) the failed validation functions. A class-structure would be ideal as the validated values can be stored as class attributes, optionally with accessors.

Comment: Wrap each input into their own while loop. I recomment writing a function that wraps `input` that tries again and again and only returns when the user input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should put each validation inside it's own `while` loop. Since this would require you to write the same code multiple times, it's a candidate for using functions:

```py
def get_input_number(question: str) -> int:
    result = input(question)
    while not result.isnumeric():
        print("Only numeric input is allowed")
        result = input(question)
    return int(result)


def get_input_alpha(question: str) -> str:
    result = input(question)
    while not result.isalpha():
        print("Only alpha input is allowed")
        result = input(question)
    return result

customer_name = get_input_alpha("Enter updated customer name:\n")
package_name = get_input_alpha("Enter updated package name:\n")
number_pax = get_input_number("Enter updated pax:\n")
pax_cost = get_input_number("Enter updated cost per pax: $\n")
```

---

**EDIT:**

So there's no built-in way to validate if a string contains only alpha and/or spaces. Again, a short helper function can do that for us. Reason to do this in a function is readability, and ease of loop control. You basically iterate over all the characters in the input string, validate, and return True/False. This allows you to easily use the return value in your while loop.

```py
def validate(something: str) -> bool:
    for c in something:
        if not(c.isalpha() or c == " "):
            return False
    return True


def get_input_alpha_space(question: str) -> str:
    result = input(question)
    while not validate(result):
        print("Only alpha input or spaces are allowed")
        result = input(question)
    return result
```

A note here, you can move the `validate` function definition to inside the function `get_input_alpha_space`, with the proper indentation. This would allow you to create a validator function inside each get_input function, and have each validator have the same name. Also it keeps the two together in one contained function.

This is very useful if you have a lot of similar functions which all need to validate something, but all in a different way. It keeps the validation function tied to the only function that calls it.

```py
def get_input_alpha_space(question: str) -> str:

    def validate(something: str) -> bool:
        for c in something:
            if not(c.isalpha() or c == " "):
                return False
        return True
        
    result = input(question)
    while not validate(result):
        print("Only alpha input, or spaces are allowed")
        result = input(question)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you! However for `get_input_alpha` if I want to accept whitespaces as well for example my input is 'hello world',  how may I do so? I tried `while not result.isalpha() or result.isspace():` but it does not work.

Comment: see my edited answer. Solution is again a small helper function

Answer (score -1):

**In this case, we can work with each input as a function**

```
customer_name = "" 
package_name = "" 
number_pax = 0 
pax_cost = 0 

def customerName(): 
    customer_name = input('Enter Updated Customer Name: ') 
    if customer_name.isalpha() == False : 
        print("Customer Name Contains Only Letters") 
        customerName() 
    
def packageName(): 
    package_name = input('Enter Package Name: ') 
    if package_name.isalpha() == False: 
        print("Package Name Contains Only Letters" )
        packageName()

def numberPax(): 
    try: 
        number_pax = int(input('Enter Number Pax: ')) 
    except ValueError as err: 
        print('Only Numbers Allowed') 
        numberPax() 

def paxCost() :
    try:    
        pax_cost = int(input('Enter Pax Cost: ')) 
    except ValueError as err: 
        print('Only Numbers Allowed, Try Again') 
        paxCost() 

while True: 
    customerName() 
    packageName() 
    numberPax() 
    paxCost()
```

Comment: This appears to be an infinite loop, and a misuse of variables.  The variables in the inner scope of the functions will not change the outer-scoped variables.  Was this tested?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: also note that since you do not use the `global` keyword, nor do your functions return anything, the values assigned (to fe. `pax_cost`) do not persist beyond the function calls.